# React: Functional component render two times the same Div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to make a web application using React and Redux. A reducer call an api of my backend and this api returns a Json of categories. But I realized when I call this reducer and the state from a component functional for someone reason the div that contains the state was rendered two times. In the first render the array of my json of categories doesn't exist but in the second render the array of my json of categories exists.

[console output of my render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMJFZ.png)

This is my component code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect} from 'react'
import { NavLink, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PrivateMenu from '../Molecules/PrivateMenu'
import PublicMenu from '../Molecules/PublicMenu'

<div className="header-list-categories-container">
                <div className="sub-list-container">
                    <label htmlFor="">{console.log('')}</label>
                    <label htmlFor="">{console.log('the div X starts')}</label>
                    <label htmlFor="">{console.log(thecategories)}</label>                     
                    <label htmlFor="">{thecategories?console.log('the array exists'):console.log('the array does not exists')}</label>
                    <label htmlFor="">{console.log('the div X ends')}</label>                                                     
                </div>
        </div>

const mapStateToProps = state =>(
    {
        thecategories : state.categoriaReducer.categories
    }
)


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header)
```

This is my app.jsx calls to my component functional Header:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Organisms/Header'
import Home from './pages/Home'

const App = ()=>(
  <Router>
    <Header />

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />


      </Switch>
  </Router>
  )

export default App;
```

and this is my index.js calls app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import store from './redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { getallcategories} from './redux/actionCreators'


store.dispatch(getallcategories())

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store ={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>
,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Your component code is clearly not the real code! (it is not a function, just some jsx out in the middle of the file!), BUT do you actually have a question? 
React will render it twice: first at start compile time, and then compile it again after this "getllcategories" async method has updated your state...

Comment: The call to your api is asynchronous,  so while its waiting for the categories to come back from the ali, It'll render the component first, with empty categories. Then it'll re render once the call is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you're describing is a normal behavior when fetching data asynchronously from backend - a component renders without the data during mount and then, when its props change (`react-redux` injects them), React rerenders it, as it should, with the actual data.

The general convention is to display some information to a user when there is no data available yet - either a load spinner or a custom "empty list" component.

Example:

```
// your Header component would look like so

// I've defaulted the 'thecategories' prop to an empty array for ease of use
const Header = ({ thecategories = []}) => {
  if (thecategories.length === 0) {
    return (<div>No data available.</div>);
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="header-list-categories-container">
        <div className="sub-list-container">
          <label htmlFor="">{console.log('')}</label>
          <label htmlFor="">{console.log('the div X starts')}</label>
          <label htmlFor="">{console.log(thecategories)}</label>                     
          <label htmlFor="">{console.log('the array always exists at this point ;)')}</label>
          <label htmlFor="">{console.log('the div X ends')}</label>                                                     
        </div>
      </div>)
  };
);
```